# How to fix PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in Wordpress template?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, e-notices

I'm working on a Wordpress template `content-article.php`

Here are the segment of my code:

```
$article_field[];
$article_field[] = 'test1';
$article_field[] = 'test2';
$article_field[] = 'test3';

echo $article_field[($page->ID + $page) % 3];
```

The PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object, is taking place at the line of `echo`

Even there's a warning, the script still execute fine and giving me correct result.

I'm rotating the `$article_field[]` element display based on pagination variable `$page`, where array index is calculated by current `page id` + `page number` % 3

How do I fix this PHP Notice?

Comment: `$page` is obviously not an object. And if it was `$page->ID + $page` would be nonsence. There is not enough code to say any more than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong, but if I've understood you right you want to get current post id? 
If yes,

```
$post_id = get_the_id()
```

and your output will be something like this:

```
echo $article_field[($post_id + $page) % 3];
```

Comment: And the notice you get in case of using $page as the object with the property called ID, but $page is not the object and can't have properties.

Comment: It was indeed a typo, using `$post->ID` resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think $page is an integer not an object so $page->ID return 0. Just remove $page->ID and use only $page % 3